# Prove $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos(x))dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin(x))dx$ with hint

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

Assume $f$ is *continuous*, prove $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos(x))dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin(x))dx$...

I was given a hint, $\sin x=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)$. I used this property to get $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin x)dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x))dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos \frac{\pi}{2})dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\cos(x))dx$. I am a few steps away, and I know $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$, but I only have $f(0)$, which is not $0$. If I can make it $0$, then I'm done. What is the additional step needed here?

Comment: Make a substitution $u = \pi/2 - x$ in your integral.

Comment: This statement is not true. Consider $f=\operatorname{id}$. **EDIT:** Nevermind, silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @K.defaoite: Did you actually work through this "counter example"?

Comment: @Bumblebee I did, incorrectly. Hence the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Use King's property
**Proof**. If $x=a+b−y$ then
$$
\int_{x=a}^{x=b}f(x)dx=\int_{y=b}^{y=a}f(a+b-y)d(a+b-y)=\\
=\int_{y=b}^{y=a}f(a+b-y)(-dy)=\\
=-\int_{y=b}^{y=a}f(a+b-y)dy=\\
=\int_{y=a}^{y=b}f(a+b-y)dy
$$
Now again you can change the dummy variable and the property is proven to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Well, use the King's Rule of Integration:
$$\int_a^bg(x)\,\text{d}x=\int_a^bg(a+b-x)\,\text{d}x$$

> For proof, substitute $u=a+b-x$ so that $\text{d}u=-\text{d}x$. The limits become $b$ to $a$. So, our integral is
>  $$\int_b^a-g(a+b-x)\,\text{d}x=\int_a^bg(a+b-x)\,\text{d}x$$

Here,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\cos x)\,\text{d}x$$$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f\left(0+\frac{\pi}{2}-\cos x\right)\,\text{d}x$$
$$=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}f(\sin x)\,\text{d}x$$

---

Alternatively, just substitute $u=\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x$ so that $\text du=-\text dx$, and $0\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}\rightarrow0$. So, the integral becomes
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0-f\Bigg(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-u\right)\Bigg)\,\text du$$
$$=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin u)\,\text du$$
$$=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f(\sin x)\,\text dx$$
Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: the OP should also prove the Kings rule otherwise it trivialises the problem

Comment: @BenjaminWang: Done!